# How to improve Kubernetes security especially inter-Pods?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

TL;DR Kubernetes allows all containers to access all other containers on the entire cluster, this seems to greatly increase the security risks. How to mitigate?

Unlike [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), where one would usually only allow network connection between containers that need to communicate (via `--link`), each *Pod* on [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/) can access all other Pods on that *cluster*.

That means that for a standard Nginx + PHP/Python + MySQL/PostgreSQL, running on Kubernetes, a compromised Nginx would be able to access the database.

People used to run all those on a single machine, but that machine would have serious periodic updates (more than containers), and SELinux/AppArmor for serious people.

One can mitigate a bit the risks by having each project (if you have various independent websites for example) run each on their own cluster, but that seems wasteful.

The current [Kubernetes security](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/security.md) seems to be very incomplete. Is there already a way to have a decent security for production?

Comment: sounds like a job for a firewall

Comment: @hanshenrik IPs are assigned dynamically by Kubernetes. It's possible to force a given IP but that's not meant for such use case. Also most Kubernetes cloud providers may not provide access to that.

Comment: On  a side-note be aware that Docker containers on the same host can access each other regardless of whether they are linked unless you start the daemon with -icc=false.

Comment: @AdrianMouat Interesting, I didn't know about that. From the doc it looks like the default is `--icc=true`, which makes no sense at all to me. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

In the not-too-distant future we will introduce controls for network policy in Kubernetes.  As of today that is not integrated, but several vendors (e.g. Weave, Calico) have policy engines that can work with Kubernetes.

Comment: I hope it'll be close to `docker-compose` way, in the sense that unless a `kubectl` command was run that says A links to B, A should not be allowed to access B (e.g. if A has a security flaw exploited).

Comment: @tim-hockin, has the “not-too-distant future” arrived yet? It'd be great to get an update on this answer, and link to any network policies best practices for Kubernetes.

Comment: Yep. NetworkPolicy exists as a beta API since Kubernetes v1.3

Answer (score 1):

As @tim-hockin says, we do plan to have a way to partition the network.

But, IMO, for systems with more moving parts, (which is where Kubernetes should really shine), I think it will be better to focus on application security.

Taking your three-layer example, the PHP pod should be authorized to talk to the database, but the Nginx pod should not.  So, if someone figures out a way to execute an arbitrary command in the Nginx pod, they might be able to send a request to the database Pod, but it should be rejected as not authorized.

I prefer the application-security approach because:

- I don't think the `--links` approach will scale well to 10s of different microservices or more.  It will be too hard to manage all the links.
- I think as the number of devs in your org grows, you will need fine grained app-level security anyhow.

In terms of being like docker compose, it looks like docker compose currently only works on single machines, according to this page:
https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/SWARM.md

Comment: I don't understand well the "scale" problem. In Kubernetes world, yes it's an issue given the current configuration because nothing says nginx talks to php (and not MySQL) in the configuration. In Docker (docker-compose and swarm) world however `--link` is the way of defining "services" in some way. So there isn't an issue of managing more complex configuration: If config say A talks to B, the system sets up an allowed channels, and only then (or so it should). So configuration is law.